# Excel checkbox feature for Quality Assurance table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm working in an excel data sheet and I have a developer checkmark in one cell. My intention is have the checkmark, once clicked to either copy or vlookup information on the previous 8 cells of the same row and have it copy to another tab of the same formatting/spacing. This may seem like a very complicated way of avoiding copy and pasting, however excel skills for others in my group and warehouse a very minimal.

[Main cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5cb5.png)

I've tried with formulas to detected the checkmark and nothing works as either =If or =Iferror(vlookup... but these do not detect the check box and having it as true or false does not yield the results needed.

Comment: What cell is assigned to the checkmark?

Comment: H column H3 and and down

Comment: `=IF(H3=1,[vlookup],"")` something like that, but that means that the values would turn blank when untagged. If you want to actually store the values you need to tag VBA (which I think you need)

Comment: The problem with that is it's not detecting the check boxes if they they are checked or unchecked.

Comment: Right click the checkbox and go to format control And link the cell you need https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-check-box-or-option-button-form-controls-9f201e46-8f6b-4a9d-a320-f44b28088cb0